# Element property to get whole Tag String

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a Element property (something like `innerHTML` or `outerHTML`) to get the String representation of the Tag

I know it's hard to explain in my question title, but this is an example.

```
<div id="div1" align="center" style="border:1px solid red">
 This is some text in a div element!
</div>
```

Expected output is

```
<div id="div1" align="center" style="border:1px solid red">
```

If such thing is not available then, best way in my mind is to do this by using `outerHTML` + regex.

Comment: @Alberto; oh yes, I search everywhere but didn't find this.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this quick solution to fetch the  parent tag :-

```
var element = document.getElementById("div1")
var formatedTag = element.outerHTML.replace(element.innerHTML, "");

console.log(formatedTag); // result :- "<div id="div1" align="center" style="border:1px solid red"></div>"
```

Hope this should help!